# How do you implement goto in F#?

Tags: f#, goto

All my favorite languages have a `goto` command. That is, you can create a label, and then later interrupt the flow of the program to go to the label. One of the more useful applications of this construct is to create an infinite loop, like this:

```
 start:
 goto start
```

Unfortunately, if I undertstand the compiler errors correctly, I can't use this same syntax in F#. So, since it doesn't seem to be supported natively, how can I implement the `goto` command in F#?

Surely, F# is a powerful enough language to implement a feature as simple as this. Other languages, such as Javascript, which do not natively support `goto`, are [still able to implement it](http://summerofgoto.com/) through a plug-in.

Further, I feel that F#, as one of the languages in the functional programming paradigm, should be able to support higher-level `goto`s: where you can pass `goto`s to `goto`s.

Comment: btw: is this a joke? I look at your rep and you sureley know this!

Comment: I'm with you--jumping into the middle of a nested closure sounds like great fun!

Comment: Alas, `goto` isn't even [reserved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233249.aspx) for future use. I fear there are no plans to implement this much needed feature.

Comment: Lambda: The Ultimate Goto http://repository.readscheme.org/ftp/papers/ai-lab-pubs/AIM-443.pdf

Comment: I sense a joke here...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A label has a lot in common with a function: they both act as entry points to some code to be executed.  Given that similarity, you can do the following:

```
let goto f = f()

let test() =
  let label = (fun () ->
    //rad code
    )
  //tight code
  goto label
```

One minor drawback is having to wrap all your code in closures. I don't know--doesn't seem too bad for getting something as handy as `goto`.

Comment: I love this answer ... but you should make say "let rec test..." after all we want to call goto even inside the block

Comment: Why does `goto` need to call itself?

Comment: @Daniel I'm curious.  How would you convert the c goto example I gave with this pattern you presented?

Comment: @gradbot: You just wrap all your function calls with `goto`: `goto do_read` etc. My answer is lame. All `goto` does is call a function. But its syntax is similar to what the OP wants (I think).

Answer (score 8):

You can get the behavior of a GOTO in F# with mutually recursive functions.  Tail call optimization allows for this goto nature and doesn't push anything onto the stack.

```
int parse() 
{
    Token   tok;

reading:
    tok = gettoken();
    if (tok == END)
        return ACCEPT;
shifting:
    if (shift(tok))
        goto reading;
reducing:
    if (reduce(tok))
        goto shifting;
    return ERROR;
}
```

Here do_read, do_shift and re_reduce act as labels.

```
type Token = END | SOMETHINGELSE

type Status = ACCEPT | ERROR

let parse gettoken shift reduce () =
    let rec do_read() =
        match gettoken() with
        | END -> ACCEPT
        | _ as tok -> do_shift tok

    and do_shift tok =
        if shift tok then
            do_read()
        else
            do_reduce tok

    and do_reduce tok =
        if reduce tok then
            do_shift tok
        else
            ERROR

    do_read()
```

Code source http://sharp-gamedev.blogspot.com/2011/08/forgotten-control-flow-construct.html

Comment: As I was pointing out in my (tongue-in-cheek) answer: there's really not much difference between a label and a function call. The biggest difference is probably fall-through...which I have no idea how you could implement in F#. Yours, of course, works because every function ends with a function call. Nice answer.

Comment: @Daniel: Fall through is just tail calling the next function at the end of the previous function.

Answer (score 8):

> Unfortunately, if I undertstand the compiler errors correctly, I can't use this same syntax in F#. So, since it doesn't seem to be supported natively, how can I implement the goto command in F#?

As Daniel said, a label and its following instruction block can be translated into a function and its body. Then each `goto` becomes a function call. You must pass all local variables as arguments because separate functions have separate scopes and you must add fall-through calls from one instruction block to the next when necessary. However, tail calls are a more general concept.

Your `start` loop example becomes:

```
let rec start () =  // .start
  start()           // goto start
```

Note that a decent compiler will actually compile this equivalent high-level code back down to `jump`/`branch` between instruction blocks in assembler. The main difference is that the stack frames must be reorganised because you can tail call between completely dissimilar environments.

> Further, I feel that F#, as one of the languages in the functional programming paradigm, should be able to support higher-level gotos: where you can pass gotos to gotos.

Yes indeed. You cannot pass labels around in other languages but you can pass functions around in F#, both as arguments in function calls and as return values from functions. Other languages, like Fortran, do offer computed `goto` as a half-way house.

Note that asynchronous programming is an important practical application of this technique. When you call an asynchronous function you tell it where it is to branch to when it completes. For example, when you make a call to start an web page downloading asynchronously you pass it a function that it will invoke once the data is available (essentially, the hardware interrupt received when the last of your data comes in ends up firing off your high-level managed code to operate on the fresh data, which is pretty cool). Modern languages give you the tools to write high-level reusable asynchronous code by combining these `goto`-like techniques with extra code generation during compilation. In other languages like C# you are screwed because you want to wrap multiple asynchronous calls in a single `try..catch` but you cannot because they are actually spread across many different functions.

Answer (score 5):

One approach that is not mentioned in the other answers is to create your own computation builder. I wrote two articles that implement some imperative features for F# in a computation builder `imperative { .. }` (read the [first one](http://tomasp.net/blog/imperative-i-return.aspx) and the [second one](http://tomasp.net/blog/imperative-ii-break.aspx)).

They don't go as far as to implement `goto`, but they implement `continue` and `break`. You could add support for `goto`, but you could only jump *back* to the labels that were executed before. Here is an example using `continue`:

```
imperative { 
  for x in 1 .. 10 do 
    if (x % 3 = 0) then do! continue
    printfn "number = %d" x }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [source code](http://summerofgoto.com/js/goto.js), you'll find that goto.js is implemented as a textual preprocessor of the code. It uses regular expressions to find and replace labels and gotos with proper Javascript constructs.

You can use this approach to extend *any language* (including F# of course). In .NET you could probably use [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) in a similar way. However, manipulating a language at the textual level is usually more of a hack than a proper extension (goto.js's author himself says "Seriously. Never use this."), this kind of metaprogramming is often instead done by hooking into the language AST.

> Surely, F# is a powerful enough language to implement a feature as simple as this.

F# actually has very poor support for metaprogramming. Languages with good metaprogramming capabilities include any Lisp, OCaml (via [campl4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camlp4)), Haskell (via [Template Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell)), [Nemerle](http://nemerle.org/Macros), [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/140), [Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/Syntactic+Macros). [Traceur](http://code.google.com/p/traceur-compiler/) implements proper javascript AST metaprogramming capabilities. But AFAIK there's nothing like this for F# yet.

> should be able to support higher-level gotos

GOTOs aren't first-class values in any language I know, so the term "higher-level GOTO"  doesn't make sense. However if you're really interested in flow control manipulation in functional languages you should look into [continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation).

Comment: I think you are being a bit hard on F# when you write it "has very poor support for metaprogramming". Features such as custom workflows, quotations and to some extent type providers may not be the ultimate metaprogramming tools, but IMO they deserve more than being described as "very poor"!

Comment: @Joh : I wouldn't characterize custom workflows as metaprogramming. Quotations and even type providers are still poor compared to the other metaprogramming facilities I describe for other languages... Ramon Snir's macros project is similar to them, that's why it's so cool.