# How do you implement comefrom in F#?

Tags: f#, comefrom

I've begun to be accustomed to the F# way of [implementing `goto`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127417/how-do-you-implement-goto-in-f) control flow, but I'm not quite sure how I can handle [`comefrom`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMEFROM), a la [INTERCAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INTERCAL).

`comefrom` is a very useful construct that allows you to jump from a label. The following example program uses it to print the complete instructions for washing your hands:

```
comefrom repeat
Console.Write "Lather"
Console.Write "Rinse"
repeat
```

The beauty of `comefrom` is that you can put a label in multiple places.

```
comefrom restart
Console.Write "Do you want to restart this program?"
let a = Console.ReadLine()
match a with
| "Y" -> restart
| _   -> Console.Write "Too bad! It will restart whether you like it or not!"
         restart
```

I tried both of these programs, but the capricious F# compiler decided to disappoint me. How can I take advantage of `comefrom` in F#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty close to the syntax you want.

```
let comefrom f = 
  let rec g = (fun () -> f g)
  f g

comefrom (fun restart ->
  Console.Write "Do you want to restart this program?"
  let a = Console.ReadLine()
  match a with
  | "Y" -> restart()
  | _   -> Console.Write "Too bad! It will restart whether you like it or not!"
           restart())
```

Once you wrap your head around a function, `f`, accepting a function, `g`, which itself is passed to `f`, it's relatively straightforward.

Migrating INTERCAL code to F# is hard. This hopefully should reduce the work involved.

Comment: neat, reminds me of my little experiment "abstracting the tail-recursive loop": http://fssnip.net/4M

Comment: Yes, looks similar. In fact, you could probably do the very same thing: `loop (* comefrom *) (fun loop -> if continue then loop() else Unchecked.defaultof<_>)`

Comment: This could be useful for a menu system.  Instead of calling restart at the end you could pass it on to another sub menu.

Answer (score 3):

```
let rec restart() =
    Console.Write "Do you want to restart this program?"
    let a = Console.ReadLine()
    match a with
    | "Y" -> restart()
    | _   -> Console.Write "Too bad! It will restart whether you like it or not!"
             restart()
```

?

Comment: This is a program that does the same thing, but it does not use a `comefrom` command. I need to implement a compatible `comefrom` command so that I don't have to completely rewrite legacy code.

Comment: @Peter : You appear to be writing in a different _language_ than your legacy code -- and you expect to not have to rewrite some, if not all, of it?

Comment: @Peter - good luck with that project :) When you finish it, please publish it (or bits of it) so we'll all see how you solved all these problems. I wonder, why do you insist on using F#? It just wasn't designed to deal with `goto` and `comefrom`.

Answer (score 3):

I think that `comefrom` corresponds to function declarations even better than `goto`.

> If you're doing something like `goto` in F#, then your label corresponds to function declaration and the `goto` command corresponds to function call. In case of `comefrom`, the `comefrom` command corresponds to function declaration and the label corresponds to function call.

Using functions, your code looks like this (**EDIT:** *which is the same thing as what Ramon already posted, but I'll keep the answer here, because it has additional explanation*):

```
let rec restart() =
  Console.Write "Do you want to restart this program?"
  let a = Console.ReadLine()
  match a with
  | "Y" -> restart()
  | _   -> Console.Write "Too bad! It will restart whether you like it or not!"
           restart()
```

If you really want to use syntax that resembles `comefrom` command then take a look at the options below. However, I don't really see the point - if you're adapting some legacy code, then you'll have to translate many other things to F# and using a weird syntax will just make F# less idiomatic. There is no way to add a new *real* syntactic construct like `comefrom` to F#.

```
let rec restart = comefrom (fun () ->
  Console.Write "Do you want to restart this program?"
  // (omitted)
  restart())

// where 'comefrom' is just a trivial wrapper for a function
let comefrom f () = f ()
```

Alternatively, you could define `comefrom` computation builder and then use the following syntax:

```
let rec restart = comefrom {
  Console.Write "Do you want to restart this program?"
  // (omitted)
  return! restart() }
```

(This [blog post](http://tomasp.net/blog/imperative-i-return.aspx) gives a very simple example of computation builder that you could adapt)